# Generate pruned package.json with nx

Tags: nrwl

I am using Nx with esbuild (my executor is `@nx/esbuild:esbuild`) and want the build to generate a package.json with the relevant 3rd party libraries.

I've set: `"generatePackageJson": true` and `"thirdParty": true`.

When running nx build, it generates what I want (it looks correct), but I get this warning:

```
Your build has conflicting options, bundle:false and thirdParty:true. Your package.json depedencies might not be generated correctly so we added an update thirdParty:false
```

When I manually set `"thirdParty": false` - my generated package.json no longer has any dependencies.

I am using nx v 16.1.0

What is the correct way to generate a pruned package.json, and leave the build files unbundled?